# Как сформировать http запрос на C# с использованием WebClient?

Tags: http, webclient

POST /task/game/start HTTP/1.1

Authorization: token

Как сделать данный запрос на  C# с использованием WebClient?
Я сколько ни пытался выходит 401 обшибка.

Comment: Пытался - значит есть код. Есть код - значит его можно и нужно приложить к вопросу. Прикладывайте, будем смотреть, что не так сделали. Или посмотрите [ранее заданные вопросы на so со словом webclient](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20webclient) - их же уже тыщу раз задавали.

Answer (score 0):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

может так?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вопрос про http, а не https. И в общем-то этой одной строчкой запрос не скачать, вы бы привели законченный фрагмент. Пока даже на комментарий не тянет.

Comment: Выложите пример вашего кода, а то так сложновато понять что именно вы пытаетесь сделать